# django jquery autocomplete list not shown

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-autocomplete

I'm in position where the `autocomplete` triggers a http request using `get` and `q` attribute.  I managed to process the `q` input and produced a result list.

then I serialized the list into `json` and send it back, but somehow I can't see the result.

This is my view code:

```
def autocomplete_company(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
        companies = Company.objects.filter(name__icontains = q ).order_by('name')[:10]
        results = companies.values_list('name', flat=True)
        data = simplejson.dumps([unicode(r) for r in results])
    else:
        data = 'fail'

    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
```

AJAX:

```
$(function(){
  $("#search_type").autocomplete("/company/autocomplete/",{
    minChars: 2
  });
});
```

any thoughts?

Comment: what does your ajax function look like?

Comment: is there any error in ajax , check the browser's console . Does the server actually receive the request?

Comment: I'm getting firebug, How can i see if the browser gets the response?

Comment: Firebug says: TypeError: data.split is not a function
http://localhost:8000/media/js/autocomplete.js
Line 368

Comment: This is the exact line:  var rows = data.split("\n");
I dont have newline characters at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass the querystring 'q' in your request

```
$(function(){
  $("#search_type").autocomplete("/company/autocomplete/?q='your_search_string'",{
    minChars: 2
  });
});

q = request.GET.get('q', '')
```

Comment: I'm getting the querystring back in django.
for somehow the browser did not get the reponse